# Why is merge sort not working in javsascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

I have tried the entire day, and can't seem to be able to find out why it is not working. I think that the problem is my skills with JavaScript language. I might be missing some concept on parameter passing. Can you please show me where is the error?

So here is the code (you can try direct on Chromes console, just copy/paste and it will "work"):

```
let arr1 = ['1','3','18']
let arr2 = ['13','14', '19']

let i = 0;
let j = 0;
let dummarr = []
while(i < arr1.length && j< arr2.length ){
      if(arr1[i] < arr2[j]){
        dummarr.push(arr1[i])
        i++;
      }else{
        dummarr.push(arr2[j])
        j++;
      }
}


//copying remaining elements.
while(i < arr1.length){
  dummarr.push(arr1[i])
  i++
}

while(j < arr2.length){
  dummarr.push(arr2[j])
  j++
}


console.log(dummarr)
```

am getting following output

```
[ '1', '13', '14', '19', '3', '18' ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are not using numbers in your array but strings. You can change the string values to numbers when you declare the arrays.

Or you can parse the strings to numbers using: `parseInt(arr1[i])`

```js
let arr1 = [1,3,18]
let arr2 = [13,14,19]

let i = 0;
let j = 0;
let dummarr = []
while(i < arr1.length && j< arr2.length ){
      if(arr1[i] < arr2[j]){
        dummarr.push(arr1[i])
        i++;
      }else{
        dummarr.push(arr2[j])
        j++;
      }
}


//copying remaining elements.
while(i < arr1.length){
  dummarr.push(arr1[i])
  i++
}

while(j < arr2.length){
  dummarr.push(arr2[j])
  j++
}


console.log(dummarr)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing them as strings and "12" < "2".
Because you have only numbers as strings, you can modify line 8 like this:

```
if (arr1[i] * 1 < arr2[j] * 1)
```

Number as string * 1 is converting it to number. Example:

```
'13' * 1 = 13
typeof '13' // string
typeof '13' * 1 //number
```

Also I'd recommend you to use Array.prototype.sort. This is how:

```
const arr1 = ["1", "3", "18"]
const arr2 = ["13", "14", "19"]

const concatArr = arr1.concat(arr2)

const sortedArr = concatArr.sort((a, b) => a - b)

console.log(sortedArr)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can concat first both arrays:

```
const result = arr1.concat(arr2);
```

And then sort it:

```
result.sort((a, b) => a - Number(b));
```